# How to have 2 mod folders, each for a different version

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

So I use Forge, and I use Hypixel SkyBlock mods. But recently after getting exposed to the Create mod, I can't seem to find a way to seperate my **1.18.2** mods from my **1.8.9** mods. Do I just put them all in one folder, or do I need another mod folder? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have all those mods in one folder. The easiest way would be to just create another instance (a completely new .minecraft folder). Obviously, call it like ".minecraft_1.8" or something. You can change the startup directory for the Forge profile by clicking "Browse" in the launcher:

[image: Edit profile]

Then, just put all your 1.8 mods into a mods folder in the .minecraft_1.8 folder